# Eclipse CDT (CCS) Goto Definition of a function

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I worked with Eclipse/CCS (CDT) on Windows XP the operations "Open Declaration" (`F3`) and "Open Definition" (`Ctrl-F3`) were functional as expected.

After switching to Windows 7 I can still jump to the declaration. But Eclipse ignores the `Ctrl-F3` and the corresponding menu command completely. I checked all preferences but could not find any difference between both installations.

I don't think that the project properties are critical here, since Open Definition still works when I access the project when Windows XP is booted.

How can I get this valuable function with the new Eclipse installation again?

Answer (score 2):

F3 works in both directions (CDT8.1)

Comment: Ctrl-F3 or Ctrl-Click or F3 does not jump to function definition, only declaration. CDT version: 8.1.0.201206111645 Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I want to correct my previous statement. It can jump to function definition if it is in the same file, or a function declaration if it is in a different .h file. However, it cannot jump to function definition in another .c file (including .C, .cpp etc).